# Failed to merge bones

Tags: animation, unreal-5

I tried to use two different fbx models as a ue mannequin, but I got an error every time: FAILED TO MERGE BONES:

This could happen if significant hierarchical changes have been made
e.g. inserting a bone between nodes.
Would you like to regenerate the Skeleton from this mesh?

WARNING: THIS MAY INVALIDATE OR REQUIRE RECOMPRESSION OF ANIMATION DATA. I really don't know what to do anymore since I've tried a bunch of models and reviewed a lot of tutorials and nothing helped me. Due to this error, the animation of running from the ue stage dummy to a custom model is also not retargeted.

Videos

https://watch.wave.video/cSODlplribCyqfob

https://watch.wave.video/CuIBYJliMZ1IzpMN

Files from video:
https://www.mediafire.com/folder/i7tub5yfkn2oe/fbx_files